# Wing IDE's PEP8 checking error

Tags: python, pep8, wing-ide

I installed PEP8 plugin for Wing IDE and now I get error when validate any `.PY`:

```
Error::Error executing script .user.internal_script_C0x3a0x5cUsers0x5chome0x5cAppData0x5cRoaming0x5cWing0x20IDE0x2050x5cscripts_pep8panel.pep8_execute
Runtime failure details:
Exception: "<type 'exceptions.UnicodeDecodeError'>"
Value = "'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc4 in position 21: invalid continuation byte"
Traceback:
  File "C:\src\ide\bin\2.7\src\command\commandmgr.pyo", line 823, in Execute
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\Wing IDE 5\scripts\pep8panel.py", line 114, in pep8_execute
    _pep8_execute(filenames)
  File "C:\Users\home\AppData\Roaming\Wing IDE 5\scripts\pep8panel.py", line 282, in _pep8_execute
    handler = app.AsyncExecuteCommandLineE(cmd, rundir, env, *args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 5.0\bin\wingapi.py", line 832, in AsyncExecuteCommandLineE
    handler = spawn.CAsyncExecute(cmd, env, dirname, 10000.0, 100000, *args)
  File "C:\src\svn-mirror-ide\bin\2.7\src\wingutils\spawn.pyo", line 1233, in __init__
  File "C:\src\svn-mirror-ide\bin\2.7\src\wingutils\spawn.pyo", line 1142, in CreatePopenE
  File "C:\src\svn-mirror-ide\bin\2.7\src\wingutils\spawn.pyo", line 986, in __init__
  File "C:\src\svn-mirror-ide\bin\2.7\src\wingutils\spawn.pyo", line 200, in _win32_cmd_line_from_argv
```

What's wrong?

**UPD**: I use Russian Windows 7 and russian letters can appear only in path to Python files.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have written your script in some legacy encoding. Try removing any non-ASCII characters (strings in some language other than English, Hawai'ian, or Latin are often the culprits. 0xC4 in Latin-1 is Ä).

If that solves your problem, either encode any non-ASCII strings as hex sequences (`'g\xf6\xf6dbye w\xf6rld'`) or re-save as UTF-8. (Then maybe add `# encoding: utf-8` near the top of the file to keep Python happy.)

Comment: Yes, appears the script doesn't handle non-ascii characters in file names, as it's failing in building a command line.  You may want to contact the script's author.